# How to read two files parallely with two map task running in parallel

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Please go a little easy on me cause I am only 3 months old in Hadoop and Mapreduce.

I've 2 files 120 MB each, The data inside each file is completely unstructured but with a common pattern. Because of the varying structure of data my requirement can not be sufficed by the default LineInputFormat.

Hence While reading the file I override the isSplitable() method and stop the split by returning false. so that 1 mapper can access one complete file and I can perform my logic and achieve the requirement.

My machine can run two mappers in parallel, So by stopping the split i am degrading the performance by running the mapper one by one for each file rather then running two mappers parallely for a file.

My Question is How can I run two mappers in parallel for both the files so the performance improves.

For Example

```
When split was allowed:
    file 1: split 1 (1st mapper) || split 2 (2nd mapper)------ 2 min 
    file 2: split 1 (1st mapper) || split 2 (2nd mapper)------ 2 min

    Total Time for reading two files =====  4 min

When Split not allowed:
    file 1: no parallel jobs so (1st mapper)---------4 min
    file 2: no parallel jobs so (1st mapper)---------4 min

    Total Time to read two files ===== 8 min (Performance degraded)

What I want
    File 1 (1st Mapper) || file 2 (2nd Mapper) ------4 min

    Total time to read two files ====== 4 min
```

Basically I want both the Files to be read at the same time by two different mapper.

Please help me in achieving the scenario.

Below are my Custom InputFormat and Custom RecordReader Code.

```
public class NSI_inputformatter extends FileInputFormat<NullWritable, Text>{
@Override
public boolean isSplitable(FileSystem fs, Path filename)
{
    //System.out.println("Inside the isSplitable Method of NSI_inputformatter");
    return false;
}

@Override
public RecordReader<NullWritable, Text> getRecordReader(InputSplit split,
        JobConf job_run, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //System.out.println("Inside the getRecordReader method of NSI_inputformatter");

    return new NSI_record_reader(job_run, (FileSplit)split);
}

}
```

Record Reader:

```
public class NSI_record_reader implements RecordReader<NullWritable, Text> 
{
FileSplit split;
JobConf job_run;
String text;
public boolean processed=false;
public NSI_record_reader(JobConf job_run, FileSplit split)
{
    //System.out.println("Inside the NSI_record_reader constructor");
    this.split=split;
    this.job_run=job_run;

    //System.out.println(split.toString());
}
@Override
public boolean next(NullWritable key, Text value) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //System.out.println("Inside the next method of the NLI_record_reader");
    if (!processed)
    {
        byte [] content_add=new byte[(int)(split.getLength())];
        Path file=split.getPath();
        FileSystem fs=file.getFileSystem(job_run);
        FSDataInputStream input=null;


        try{
            input=fs.open(file);
            System.out.println("the input is " +input+ input.toString());
            IOUtils.readFully(input, content_add, 0, content_add.length);
            value.set(content_add, 0, content_add.length);
        }
        finally
        {
            IOUtils.closeStream(input);

        }
        processed=true;
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

@Override
public void close() throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public NullWritable createKey() {
    System.out.println("Inside createkey() mrthod of NSI_record_reader");
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return  NullWritable.get();
}

@Override
public Text createValue() {
    System.out.println("Inside createValue() mrthod of NSI_record_reader");
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return new Text();
}

@Override
public long getPos() throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("Inside getPs() mrthod of NSI_record_reader");
    return processed ? split.getLength() : 0;
}

@Override
public float getProgress() throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("Inside getProgress() mrthod of NSI_record_reader");
    return processed ? 1.0f : 0.0f;
}

}
```

Input Sample:

```
<Dec 12, 2013 1:05:56 AM CST> <Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101017>       <[weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext@42e87d99 - appName: 'Agile', name:    '/Agile', context-path: '/Agile', spec-version: 'null'] Root cause of ServletException.
  javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
at com.agile.ui.web.taglib.common.FormTag.writeFormHeader(FormTag.java:498)
at com.agile.ui.web.taglib.common.FormTag.doStartTag(FormTag.java:429)
at jsp_servlet._default.__login_45_cms._jspService(__login_45_cms.java:929)
at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspBase.service(JspBase.java:34)
at    weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.ja va:227)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
Retrieving the value for the attribute Page Two.Validation Status for the Object 769630
Retrieving the value for the attribute Page Two.Pilot Required for the Object 769630
Retrieving the value for the attribute Page Two.NPO Contact for the Object 769630
<Dec 12, 2013 1:12:13 AM CST> <Warning> <Socket> <BEA-000449> <Closing socket as no         data read from it during the configured idle timeout of 0 secs>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered using a custom [inputformat](https://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module5.html#fileformat)? Can you paste a sample of your input file it would help in deciding if a custom inputformat will do the trick for you.

Comment: here you go I have shared my custom inputformat and custom recordreader code with the Input small piece of Input file

Comment: I've Already framed a custom InputFormat to stop the split, so my complete file can be read by one mapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to set property `-D mapred.min.split.size=209715200`. In this case `FileInputFormat` should not split your files because they are smaller than `mapred.min.split.size`.

Comment: But that would mean that we still have only one mapper processing the input, is'nt it ?

Comment: From the [FileInputSplit source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/com.cloudera.hadoop/hadoop-core/0.20.2-737/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/FileInputFormat.java#FileInputFormat.getSplits%28org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext%29) it follows that if you have two files, then FileInputFormat would create at least two splits (one for each file) and every split will be processed with separate mapper.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, however just going by with the code in FileInputSplit we should have 2 mappers running, one for each input file is'nt it ? ...

Comment: Hey Alexey, I visited the link you provided But I could seldom understand it as you see I am new to mapReduce. It would be great of you If you share the part of your code and explain it in brief....  I am using Mapred the old lib.   Thanks a lot for you input...

Comment: @Sudarshan, may be more than one split (mapper) per file, as i remember default split size is 64 Mb.

Comment: @user2404193, there are a lot of hadoop examples with explanation in the web =)

Comment: @Alexey, Thanks a lot, but If you could give the content for the search I'd be glad. I did a lot of digging but got no luck

Comment: Tutorial with classic WordCount example: https://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/HadoopTutorial/CDH4/Hadoop-Tutorial.html
Simple examples: https://code.google.com/p/hadoop-map-reduce-examples/
Examples from hadoop distribution: http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/hadoop/common/trunk/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-examples/